# How to compare two folders for non identical files based on name?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two folders A and B..Inside A multiple files are there and inside B multiple files are there..I have to check files in A with files in B for non identical files...I tried like this it is giving whole search result...

```
var filesnotinboth = from f1 in dir1.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     from f2 in dir2.GetFiles("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     where f1.Name != f2.Name
                     select f1.Name;
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, for one thing that approach is very inefficient - it's going to be calling `dir2.GetFiles` each time you start with a new `f1`. It's then going to give a match for every `f2` which doesn't match the *current* `f1`. So even if it's going to match a *later* `f1`, it'll still be output. Imagine that dir1 contains A, B and C, and dir2 contains C and D. You'll end up like this:

```
f1    f2    Result of where?
 A     C    True
 A     D    True
 B     C    True
 B     D    True
 C     C    False
 C     D    True
```

So the result would be A, A, B, B, C - you'd still *have* C (which you didn't want) - just not quite as often as A and B.

You want to use set operations, like this:

```
var dir1Files = dir1.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Select(x => x.Name);

var dir2Files = dir2.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Select(x => x.Name);

var onlyIn1 = dir1Files.Except(dir2Files);
```

Now that *should* work, and more efficiently...

EDIT: I've assumed you want files in A but not in B, based on possibly an earlier version of the question. (I'm not sure whether it was edited in the first five minutes. Obviously the current code isn't going to return anything in B but not A.)

If you want the symmetric difference, use [`HashSet<T>.SymmetricExceptWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848.aspx):

```
var inExactlyOneDirectory = new HashSet<string>(dir1Files);
inExactlyOneDirectory.SymmetricExceptWith(dir2Files);
```

(Note that I dislike the fact that `SymmetricExceptWith` is a void method which mutates the existing set, instead of returning a new set or just a sequence. Aside from anything else, it means the variable name is only appropriate after the second statement, not the first.)

EDIT: If you need uniqueness by name and size, you really need an anonymous type representing both. Unfortunately, it's then hard to create a `HashSet<T>` based on it. So you'll want an extension method like this:

```
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> set)
{
    return new HashSet<T>(set);
}
```

Then:

```
var dir1Files = dir1.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Length });

var dir2Files = dir2.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Length });

var difference = dir1Files.ToHashSet();
difference.SymmetricExceptWith(dir2Files);
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The OP appears to want files that are in dir1 or dir2, but not *both*.

Comment: @Ani: It's not entirely clear, based on the original code - and I *think* the question was originally more suggestive of "A but not B" rather than the symmetric difference. But I've edited my answer to include the symmetric difference too.

Comment: @bala3569: I don't understand what you mean, but I've provided both solutions in my answer.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:just said Ani(The OP appears to want files that are in dir1 or dir2, but not both)----- i need both

Comment: @Jon Skeet:I need both non identical name and size..Is it correct  .Select(x => x.Name). Select(x => x.Length);

Comment: @bala3569: I'd also suggest that you take a step back and try to learn the basics of LINQ so you can work this sort of thing out on your own... given the existing attempt, I suspect you don't really understand what's going on behind the scenes. Taking a bit more time to learn how it works will mean you can avoid having to ask for help as often.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:ya correct jon...this is the first time am using LINQ

Comment: @Jon Skeet:Ienumerable doesnot contain definition for Tohashset...am using 3.5

Comment: @Jon Skeet:can u suggest any material to learn basics of LINQ

Comment: @bala3569: There are lots of LINQ tutorials and books around. You might want to read Pro LINQ or LINQ in Action, for example.

Comment: My reaction to [NerdDinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) (which is an ASP.NET MVC tutorial that hits LINQ but doesn't focus on it) was, "So that's why LINQ is actually useful." I think a semi-realistic jumble of code that actually *does* something is a good way to get a feel for a feature.  Tip: Don't copy the code from tutorials, retype it by hand.  It forces you to notice stuff that would be missed otherwise.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:is there any difference between SymmetricExceptWith and SymmetricDifferenceWith

Comment: @bala3569: SymmetricDifferenceWith was a typo :)

Comment: @bala3569: Exactly. I typed SymmetricDifferenceWith but meant SymmetricExceptWith.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:oh ok..i am writing the result in a text file by showing name alone                                                       var onlyIn1 = dir1Files.Except(dir2Files).Select(x => new { x.Name });
  string[] foo1 = onlyIn1.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
  File.WriteAllLines(@"d:\log1.txt", foo1);

Comment: @Jon Skeet:But here by using this i dont know how to show name alone in text file

Comment: var difference = dir1Files.ToHashSet();
difference.SymmetricExceptWith(dir2Files);                     string[] foo1 = difference.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
file.WriteAllLines(@"d:\log1.txt", foo1);

Comment: Instead of using `c => c.ToString()`, use `c => c.Name`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:fine jon..i want to show name and directory name in text file but i dont want to compare files with x.directoryname...Is it possible?

Comment: @bala3569: Well you can't store that in a string array, can you? I suggest that instead of continuing to edit this question multiple times, you ask new questions. Otherwise each time you edit the question significantly, you're invalidating the existing answers.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:Is there any other way??

Comment: @bala3569: Just don't use a string array... use the anonymous type, by declaring the variable with "var".

Comment: @Jon Skeet:my problem here is i am not comparing files with directory name..so i cant code like x.DirectoryName in the following              var onlyIn1 = dir1Files.Except(dir2Files).Select(x => new { x.Name,x.DirectoryName });

Comment: @bala3569: I thought you were going to create a new question... this is far too complicated to discuss in comments.

Comment: @bala3569:fine i will create a new question

Comment: @Jon Skeet:got solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387028/comparing-two-folders-for-non-identical-files

Comment: @Jon Skeet:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415674/compare-two-folders-for-non-identical-files-with-symmetricdifference

Comment: @bala3569: Yup, I've seen it. Don't have an answer just yet.

Answer (score 2):

Jon Skeet's answer should help you with understanding why your current solution won't work, and is fundamentally inefficient.

As for solving the problem, one option would be to use the [`HashSet.SymmetricExceptWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848.aspx) method, which "modifies the current HashSet(Of T) object to contain only elements that are present either in that object or in the specified collection, but not both."

```
// Thanks to Jon Skeet for template
var dir1Files = dir1.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Select(x => x.Name);

var dir2Files = dir2.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Select(x => x.Name);

var filesNotInBoth = new HashSet<string>(dir1Files);

filesNotInBoth.SymmetricExceptWith(dir2Files);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var files2 = dir2.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var filesnotinboth = dir1.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         .Where(f1 => !files2.Any(f2 => f2.Name == f1.Name));
```

Comment: Why would you want to fetch all the files under `dir2` several times?

Comment: @jon: yes you're right, I was just writing while I was thinking

Comment: `filesnotinboth`? I don't think that's the question nor what your query returns