# comparing two folders for non identical files?

Tags: c#, linq

```
     var dir1Files = dir1.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Length });
    var dir2Files = dir2.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Length });
    var onlyIn1 = dir1Files.Except(dir2Files).Select(x => new { x.Name });
    File.WriteAllLines(@"d:\log1.txt", foo1);
```

Here i am comparing two files based on name and writing in a text file...
But i need to write name along with directory name...But i cannot select directory name like this

```
 var onlyIn1 = dir1Files.Except(dir2Files).Select(x => new { x.Name,x.DirectoryName });
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: All directory names will be the same, why do you need to keep them in the LINQ query result? Just take it from dir1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does using `FullName` solve your problem?

```
var onlyIn1 = dir1Files.Except(dir2Files).Select(x => new { x.FullName });
```

Alternatively you could put together a custom string within the `Select` statement:

```
// get strings in the format "file.ext, c:\path\to\file"
var onlyIn1 = dir1Files.Except(dir2Files).Select(x => 
                  string.Format("{0}, {1}", x.Name, x.Directory.FullName));
```

In order to be able to use this information in the objects, don't create anonymous types with limited information in the first steps, but rather keep the full `FileInfo` objects:

```
var dir1Files = dir1.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var dir2Files = dir2.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

**Update**
The real problem in your code sample is that `Except` will compare using the *default equality comparer*. For most types (and certainly in the case of anonymous types) this means that it will compare the object references. Since you have two lists with `FileInfo` objects, `Except` will return all objects from the first list, where the same *object instances* are not found in the second. Since none of the object instances in the first list are present also in the second, all objects from the first list will be returned.

In order to fix this (and still have access to the data that you want to store) you will need to use the [`Except` overload that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx). First, let's create the `IEqualityComparer`:

```
class FileInfoComparer : IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>
{
    public bool Equals(FileInfo x, FileInfo y)
    {
        // if x and y are the same instance, or both are null, they are equal
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x,y))
        {
            return true;
        }
        // if one is null, they are not equal
        if (x==null || y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // compare Length and Name
        return x.Length == y.Length && 
            x.Name.Equals(y.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FileInfo obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Length.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you can use that comparer to compare the files in the directories:

```
var dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\a");
var dir2 = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\b");

var dir1Files = dir1.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories); 
var dir2Files = dir2.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories); 

var onlyIn1 = dir1Files
    .Except(dir2Files, new FileInfoComparer())
    .Select(x =>  string.Format("{0}, {1}", x.Name, x.Directory.FullName));
```

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: i cant give like that..i am comparing files based on name and length only..but i have to write both name and directory name....if i put x and dot means it is showing only name and length only

Comment: Rather than selecting new { x.Name, x.Length} just select (x => x) then you'll have the entire object to filter with.

Comment: @bala3569: I missed that you create an anonymous type in the first two steps. As @Tom points out, just return `x` (which effectively means that you can skip the call to `Select` altogether). I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk:but it will compare everything.....i have to compare name alone... but have to write both name and directory name

Comment: @Tom:but it will compare everything.....i have to compare name alone but have to write both name and directory name

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk:if i use like this what i have to give                  var difference = dir1Files.ToHashSet();
                    difference.SymmetricExceptWith(dir2Files);

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk:I have to write both files from two folders

Comment: @bala3569: `SymmetricExceptWith` will use the equality comparer used by the `HashSet`. I am not familiar with `ToHashSet` so I don't know if it offers any overload accepting an `IEqualityComparer<T>`, but `var difference = new HashSet<FileInfo>(dir1Files, new FileInfoComparer());` will give you the expected behavior.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388344/comparing-two-folders-for-non-identical-files-with-symmetricdifference

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk:If i want to compare three things name,length and lastwritetime means how should i write ...Equality comparer would compare only 2 things only..any suggestion?

Comment: @bala3569: just add it to the `return` statement: `return x.Length == y.Length && x.Name.Equals(y.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && x.LastWriteTime == y.LastWriteTime;`

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk:if length differs i have to write length along with directory name or if lastwritetime differs i have to write lastwritetime along with directory name...is it possible??

Comment: @bala3569: that puts the whole code in a new light; I'd suggest you post that as a new question.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk:ok fine i ll post it as a new question

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk:Look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415674/compare-two-folders-for-non-identical-files-with-symmetricdifference