# comparing two folders for non identical files with SymmetricDifference

Tags: c#, linq

```
 var dir1Files = dir1.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
 var dir2Files = dir2.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

 var difference = dir1Files.ToHashSet(); 
 difference.SymmetricExceptWith(dir2Files);

 string[] foo1 = difference.Select(c => c.Name).ToArray();
 File.WriteAllLines(@"d:\log1.txt", foo1);
```

Here i am comparing two files based on name and writing in a text file... But i need to write name along with directory name like this [comparing two folders for non identical files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387028/comparing-two-folders-for-non-identical-files)...

Any Suggestion?

**EDIT:**
I have two folders A and B..inside that two folders lots of folders and files are there...
I am comparing these two folders for non identical files with symmetric difference and  write the name and directory name into a text file...my problem is symmetric difference is working fine and is writing both non identical file names into a log file...But i have to write file name with that directory name...

this code is working fine

```
var dir1Files = dir1.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Length });
var dir2Files = dir2.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Length });
var difference = dir1Files.ToHashSet();      
difference.SymmetricExceptWith(dir2Files);
string[] foo1 = difference.Select(c => c.Name).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(@"d:\log1.txt", foo1);
```

Here i cant give like this

```
string[] foo1 = difference.Select(c => c.Name+""+c.DirectoryName).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Ani:No if i give like this  var dir1Files = dir1.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => new { x.Name });

Comment: @Ani:it is comparing and giving non identical files..otherwise it is giving the whole search result

Comment: @bala3569: An example would really help.

Comment: @Ani:able to understand my problem??

Comment: @bala3569: I think I got it. Is my answer what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be to write your own [**`IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) implementation that enforced your definition of equality between two files.

```
public class FileInfoNameLengthEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<FileInfo>
{
    public override bool Equals(FileInfo x, FileInfo y)
    {
        if (x == y)
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        // 2 files are equal if their names and lengths are identical.
        return x.Name == y.Name && x.Length == y.Length;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(FileInfo obj)
    {
        return obj == null
               ? 0  : obj.Name.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Length.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then the rest of it would look something like (untested):

```
// Construct custom equality-comparer.
var comparer = new FileInfoNameLengthEqualityComparer();

// Create sets of files from each directory.
var sets = new[] { dir1, dir2 }
                 .Select(d => d.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                 .Select(files => new HashSet<FileInfo>(files, comparer))
                 .ToArray();

// Make the first set contain the set-difference as determined 
// by the equality-comparer.
sets[0].SymmetricExceptWith(sets[1]);

// Project each file to its full name and write the file-names
// to the log-file.
var lines = sets[0].Select(fileInfo => fileInfo.FullName).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(@"d:\log1.txt", lines);
```

Comment: @Ani:if length differs i have to write length along with directory name or if lastwritetime differs i have to write lastwritetime along with directory name...is it possible??

Comment: @Ani:If i want to compare 3 things name,length and lastwritetime means how should i write..Is there anything like EqualityComparer

Comment: @bala3569:  Add ` && x.LastWriteTime == y.LastWriteTime` to the `Equals` method. You might want to build the write-time into the hash-code method too for efficiency, but that isn't necessary for functional correctness.

Comment: @Ani:Look at this one..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415674/compare-two-folders-for-non-identical-files-with-symmetricdifference