# compare two folders for non identical files with SymmetricDifference?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two folders A and B..inside that two folders lots of folders and files are there... I am comparing these two folders for non identical files with symmetric difference and write the name and directory name into a text file...I have used this code

```
public class FileInfoNameLengthEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<FileInfo>
    {
        public override bool Equals(FileInfo x, FileInfo y)
        {
            if (x == y)
                return true;

            if (x == null || y == null)
                return false;

            // 2 files are equal if their names and lengths are identical.
   return x.Name == y.Name && x.Length == y.Length && x.LastWriteTime== y.LastWriteTime;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode(FileInfo obj)
        {
            return obj == null
                   ? 0  : obj.Name.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Length.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

// Construct custom equality-comparer.
var comparer = new FileInfoNameLengthEqualityComparer();

// Create sets of files from each directory.
var sets = new[] { dir1, dir2 }
                 .Select(d => d.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                 .Select(files => new HashSet<FileInfo>(files, comparer))
                 .ToArray();

// Make the first set contain the set-difference as determined 
// by the equality-comparer.
sets[0].SymmetricExceptWith(sets[1]);

// Project each file to its full name and write the file-names
// to the log-file.
var lines = sets[0].Select(fileInfo => fileInfo.FullName).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(@"d:\log1.txt", lines);
```

What i need is if length differs i have to write length along with directory name and if name differs i have to write name along with directory name or if lastwritetime differs i have to write lastwritetime along with directory name...Any suggestion??

In this format:

```
Missed Files detail :
---------------------
File Name           Size         Date       Path    


Discrepancies in File Size:
--------------------------

Size                 Path


Discrepancies in File Date:
--------------------------
date                 path
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546137.aspx

Comment: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_25141664.html

Comment: A excellent example of implementing Linq in compare the file content of two folders: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882649.aspx
It need though some adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels to me like you're looking for different things, really:

- Files which are present in one directory but not the other (so use symmetric difference)
- Files where they *are* present in both directories, but then:

  - Those which differ by length
  - Those which differ by last write time

I would treat these separately. You already know how to do the first part. To get the second part, you need the intersection of the two sets of filenames (just use the `Intersect` extension method). From that you can list differences:

```
var differentLengths = from name in intersection
                       let file1 = new FileInfo(directory1, name)
                       let file2 = new FileInfo(directory2, name)
                       where file1.Length != file2.Length
                       select new { Name = name,
                                    Length1 = file1.Length,
                                    Length2 = file2.Length };
```

... you can then print those out. You can then do the same for last write times.

In other words, you don't actually need a comparer which compares all of the properties at a time.

Comment: @bala3569: No, I probably wouldn't bother with an extra extension method here. I'm afraid I'm not going to keep just spoonfeeding you code for every different situation you run up against. You really need to learn LINQ for yourself now.

Comment: `Intersect` is part of standard LINQ - you don't need an extra method for it.

Comment: @bala3569: You're probably not calling it *on* anything. Again, if you try to learn LINQ from the ground up you'll understand this kind of thing.

Comment: @bala3569: No, you need to take longer than that to learn LINQ. Get a book, read several tutorials, experiment... you don't get good at this sort of thing by trying for a couple of hours and then giving up.